# Error while managing multiple controller with same name in different namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Below is the controllers defined from my end:

```
namespace Demo.Web.Controllers.Api.Admin
{
    public class UserAuthenticationController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpPost, ActionName(ActionNameConstants.PostAdminLogin)]
        public IHttpActionResult PostAdminLogin(AdminLoginModel adminLoginModel)
        {            
            return Ok(true);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace Demo.Web.Controllers.Api.Front
{
    public class UserAuthenticationController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName(ActionNameConstants.PostLogin)]
        public void Post(FrontLoginModel frontLoginModel)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Now for the above controllers we have managed routing as below:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {


            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "FrontApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/front/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "AdminApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
```

For the above controllers and routing I am facing following error:

```
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'userAuthentication'. 
This can happen if the route that services this request 
('api/admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}') found multiple controllers
defined with the same name but differing namespaces, which is not supported.
```

Kindly let me know your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED

Add `[Route("api/admin")]` to controller in namespace `Demo.Web.Controllers.Api.Admin` and `[Route("api/front")]` to controller in namespace `Demo.Web.Controllers.Api.Front`and change your Register method like the following:

```
namespace Demo.Web.Controllers.Api.Admin
{
    [Route("api/admin")]
    public class UserAuthenticationController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpPost,Route("login")]
        public IHttpActionResult PostAdminLogin([FromBody]AdminLoginModel adminLoginModel)
        {            
            return Ok(true);
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
namespace Demo.Web.Controllers.Api.Front
{
    [Route("api/front")]
    public class UserAuthenticationController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        public void Post([FromBody]FrontLoginModel frontLoginModel)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Change your void Register(HttpConfiguration config) to the following:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
}
```

Comment: can you help me out to let me know the exact place to keep it in controller?

Comment: @KunalKakkad also try to change your Register function as I have added to the answer

Comment: Getting such error:
"The object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the application's startup code after all other initialization code."